# The field "Attached File Count" is not autoincremented in the resquest "Reporting Revisions Get" of the Azure DevOps Services REST API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

The issue is that "System.AttachedFileCount" is not incremented for  8th revision. It should be 2 and not 0.

[98563-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qld0L.png)

As you can see below there are indeed 2 attached files to the Work Item :

[98520-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fs1t.png)

And there are 8 revisions :

[98478-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlHge.png)

Please, how can we fix this ? Maybe the tracking of System.AttachedFileCount is not handle by the API because if we use the field in a query it works as u can see below :
[98584-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUpOU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I could reproduce this issue in my side.

[image]

It seems that this API cannot read the value of the attachment files.

As far as I know, there should be some issues with this Rest API.

I suggest that you could submit a feedback ticket on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21).

After our engineers confirm this issue, they will report it to the Product Group and conduct further investigation.